# URL Redirect based on input but if input url does not exist do not redirect cant get PHP to work

Tags: javascript, forms, url, redirect, error-handling

@themask 
Hello and thanks for your help, I have tosed the php and now have just this code

```
<script>
document.forms[0].onsubmit = 
    function() {
       var to = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
       var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest; 
       ajax.onreadystate = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status != 404) {
                window.locaiton.replace(to);
            } else {
                window.location.replace('http://www.mysite.com/incontinence/protective_underwear/presto_protective_underwear/');
            }
    }; 
    ajax.open('GET',to);
    ajax.send(null);
};
      </script>
      <form onsubmit="location.href='http://www.mysite.com/coupons/' + document.getElementById('myInput').value; return false;" >
  <input type="text" id="myInput" />
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" />
</form>
```

But it is still sending me to incorrect urls if a bad code is used.  Its like it is skipping the java all together.

Any additional help would be great.

Thank you,
Micah

Thank you,
Micah

Answer (score 2):

Try using get_headers()

```
$headers = get_headers('http://www.activelifemed.com/incontinence/protective_underwear/presto_protective_underwear/')
if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
  //exists
}
else{
  //doesn't exist
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: I think best check if HTTP CODE is different of 404

Comment: @The Mask Hello, I am still lost.  I have thrown out the php and now have

Answer (score 0):

You can make this using JavaScript:

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = 
    function() {
       var to = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
       var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest; 
       ajax.onreadystate = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status != 404) {
                window.locaiton.replace(to);
            } else {
                window.location.replace('http://www.mysite.com/incontinence/protective_underwear/presto_protective_underwear/');
            }
    }; 
    ajax.open('GET',to);
    ajax.send(null);
};
```

Comment: @micah, you should not edit someone's answer to comment on something. You can either add a comment or edit your question.